# Find all git repos that do not contain any one of .gitignore and .gitattributes

Tags: shell-script, find, git

I basically want to find all git repos that have neither a `.gitattributes` nor a `.gitignore` file at the root.

I used `find . -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/.gitignore" ';' -print` to find it but it lists out all the directories instead of only the top level git directories.

My directory tree looks like this:

```
GitHub
├─ _Clones
|  ├─ repo1 (has .gitignore)
|  └─ repo2
├─ _Forks
|  ├─ repo1 (has .gitattributes)
|  └─ _For-Later
|      ├─ repo2
|      └─ repo3
├─ myrepo1 (has both)
├─ myrepo2 (has both)
...
└─ myrepo10
```

In such a layout I would want the output to be `_Clones\repo2`, `_Forks\_For-Later\repo2`, `_Forks\_For-Later\repo3` and `myrepo10`.

I've tried using `depth` parameter for find but that is a variable for each directory!

Comment: Both `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` can appear anywhere within the repository; do you care about that?

Comment: No. I actually want to see the repos I haven't configured properly. I learn about .gitattributes pretty recently so am looking to do a cleanup. For what you are saying, I already wrote that `find` command.

Comment: The main hurdle I'm facing is how to restrict the search to only top level git repos.

Comment: I've edited the first sentence - that seems to me to be what you want from the comment and the diagram, but check that it represents what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list the root directories of git repositories, I use the following:

```
find . -name .git -print0 | xargs -0 dirname
```

A variant finds all folders containing `.gitignore`:

```
find . -name .gitignore -print0 | xargs -0 dirname
```

Determining git repositories whose root doesn't contain `.gitignore` is then simply a set operation on the two sets of folders:

```
comm -23 <(find . -name .git -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | sort) <(find . -name .gitignore -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | sort)
```

This compares the two sets of folders (which have to be sorted) and lists those which only appear in the first set. The `<()` operation is [process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe) and allows the output of any command to be used as input to another command instead of a file.

Replace `.gitignore` with `.gitattributes` above to find the git repositories which don't contain `.gitattributes` in their root directory...

To get the final output you're after, combine both:

```
comm -23 <(comm -23 <(find . -name .git -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | sort) <(find . -name .gitignore -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | sort)) <(find . -name .gitattributes -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | sort)
```