# bash can't store hexvalue 0x00 in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, dd

I'm trying to do some tricks with dd.  I thought it would be possible to store some hexvalues in a variable called "header" to pipe it into dd.

*My first step without a variable was this:*

```
$ echo -ne "\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4" |dd of=hex
$ hd hex

00000000  36 c9 da 00 b4                                    |6....|
00000005
```

*After that I tried this:*

```
$ header=$(echo -ne "\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4") 
$ echo -n $header | hd

00000000  36 c9 da b4                                       |6...|
00000004
```

As you can see I lost my `\x00` value in the `$header` variable.
Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I get `bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`.

Comment: You are missing quotes it should be `header="$(echo -ne "\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4")"; echo -n "$header" | hd` however this just gives same result.

Comment: This works `header="\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4"; echo -n "$header" | hd`, but is not the same thing as it is storing the human readable form.

Answer (score 16):

You can't store a null byte in a string because Bash uses C-style strings, which reserve the null byte for terminators. So you need to rewrite your script to simply pipe the sequence that contains the null byte without Bash needing to store it in the middle. For example, you can do this:

```
printf "\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4" | hd
```

Notice, by  the way, that you don't need `echo`; you can use Bash's `printf` for this an many other simple tasks.

Or instead of chaining, you can use a temporary file:

```
printf "\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4" > /tmp/mysequence
hd /tmp/mysequence
```

Of course, this has the problem that the file `/tmp/mysequence` may already exist. And now you need to keep creating temporary files and saving their paths in strings.

Or you can avoid that by using process substitution:

```
hd <(printf "\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4")
```

The `<(command)` operator creates a named pipe in the file system, which will receive the output of `command`. `hd` will receive, as its first argument, the path to that pipe—which it will open and read *almost* like any file. You can read more about it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17117/136742.

Comment: While correct, this is an implementation detail and not the exact reason. I looked at it, and the POSIX standard actually _requires_ this behaviour, so there you have the _actual_ reason. (As some have pointed out, `zsh` will do it, but only in nōn-POSIX mode.) I actually looked into it because I was wondering if it was worth to implement this in `mksh`…

Comment: @mirabilos, would you care to expand on that? AFAICT, behaviour is unspecified per POSIX for command substitution when the output has NUL characters, and for zsh in POSIX mode, the only relevant difference I can think of is that in `sh` emulation, `\0` is not in the default value of `$IFS`. `echo "$(printf 'a\0b')"` still works OK in `sh` emulation in `zsh`.

Comment: @mirabilos Considering that the shells predates the POSIX standard by a decade or more, I *guess* you could find out that the actual *actual* reason is that shells used C-style strings and the standard was built around that.

Comment: I found a good Q for detailed discussion on printf versus echo. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Answer (score 9):

You can use `zsh` instead which is the only shell that can store the NUL character in its variables. That character even happens to be in the default value of `$IFS` in `zsh`.

```
nul=$'\0'
```

Or:

```
nul=$'\x0'
```

Or

```
nul=$'\u0000'
```

Or

```
nul=$(printf '\0')
```

However note that you can't pass such a variable as an argument or environment variable to a command  that is *executed* as the arguments and environment variables are NUL-delimited strings passed to the `execve()` system call (a limitation of the system's API, not the shell). In `zsh`, you can however pass NUL bytes as arguments to functions or builtin commands.

```
echo $'\0' # works
/bin/echo $'\0' # doesn't
```

Comment: "You can use zsh instead". No thanks - I'm teaching myself bash-scripting as a beginner right now.
I don't want to confuse myself with an other syntax. But thank you veray much for suggest it

Comment: As a matter of fact, you used `zsh` syntax in your question. `echo -n $header` to mean to pass the content of the `$header` variable as a last argument to `echo -n` is `zsh` (or `fish` or `rc` or `es`) syntax, not `bash`  syntax. In `bash`, that has [a very different meaning](/q/171346). More generally `zsh` is like `ksh` (`bash`, the GNU shell, being more or less a part-clone of `ksh`, the Unix de-facto shell) but with most of the design idiosyncrasies of the Bourne shell fixed (and a lot of extra features, and a  lot more user-friendly/less astonishing).

Comment: Be careful: zsh may change a zero byte sometimes: `echo $(printf 'ab\0cd') | od -vAn -tx1c`  prints `  61  62  20  63  64  0a`, that is an space where a NUL should exist.

Comment: @sorontar, yes, as I said `\0` is in the default `$IFS`, so `$(printf 'ab\0cd')` is split into `ab` and `cd`. Try with `echo "$(printf 'ab\0cd')"` instead.

Comment: And that is something no other (none, nil) shell will reproduce. That makes an script behave in very special ways in zsh. In my opinion: zsh is just trying to be too clever.

Comment: Having "fixed" the design misfeatures present in the POSIX sh standard that getting accustomed to writing zsh scripts means one is getting accustomed to practices which would be buggy if exercised in any other shell. This isn't such a problem with a syntax that's so unlike a different language that skills or habits aren't likely to transfer, but such is not the case at hand.

Comment: @sorontar, both `echo $(printf 'ab\0cd')` and `echo "$(printf 'ab\0cd')"` are unspecified in POSIX and not working "properly" in every other shell. OTOH, the behaviour is clearly specified in `zsh` and works as documented. It makes perfect sense to split on the NUL byte by default. That can be useful in `ls -ld -- $(grep -rZl whatever .)` though you'd rather write `ls -ld -- ${(0)"$(grep -rZl whatever .)"}` in that case, as you don't want to split on the other `$IFS` character.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that is a fair point. OTOH, shells like `rc` (or to some extent `fish`) with a radically different syntax and that have fixed the Bourne issues never took off for the very reason that they're not Bourne-like. IMO, `zsh`'s stance is courageous and laudable here and a step in the right direction.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I will be bold also and ask a very naive question: isn't zsh supposed to: [In ZSH, however, word splitting is disabled by default (which is great)](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/38/ZSH-Gem-3-No-automatic-word-split/), that should mean that the "Command Substitution" **string** should not be split. I am sure that I am wrong and I will be clearly corrected by stating clearly why in this particular case the naive question I am making is invalid. But that just miss the point: One has to be an expert in zsh to make it work the way one wants. Simple users easily get lost .

Comment: @sorontar, word splitting (but not globbing which would not make sense) happens in `zsh` upon command substitution, because that's generally what you want. (though in that specific case, I'm not sure I agree with that particular design decision). Generally `zsh` chooses the path of least astonishment, that's the opposite of _needing to be expert to work with it_, I can't think of where you're getting that from.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, `zsh`does not actually store raw NUL characters in a variable. Just as `ksh93` uses a 'hack' (base64) to store NUL and other characters in binary variables, `zsh` also uses a 'hack'  to store NUL (and some other characters) in a variable - a Meta byte (0x83) followed by a byte  containing 'character xor 32'. See `zsh.h`.

Comment: @fpmurphy1, that's internal only and transparent to the user. In `zsh`, `$var[1]` for instance gets the first character of `$var` whether it's a NUL character or other. How `zsh` stores it internally is irrelevant as it's not visible to the user. That's different in `ksh93`. In ksh93, If a `$var` contains the base64 encoding of `abc`, `${var:0:1}` will contain the first character of that base64 encoding, not `a`, which is not useful. `${#var}` will expand to the length of the encoding, not the length of the data it is meant to represent.

Answer (score 1):

Bash uses C strings internally which cannot store the null byte. Store the value in a temporary file like this:

```bsh
    zHex=$(mktemp --tmpdir "$(basename "$0")-XXXX")
    trap "rm -f ${zHex@Q}" EXIT
```

The variable zHex now contains a unique file name. The file referenced by $zHex can be deleted manually, but the file will be automatically deleted when the program terminates for any reason.

Then use the variable like this:

```bsh
    echo -ne "\x36\xc9\xda\x00\xb4" > "$zHex"
    hd "$zHex"
```

This does NOT store the value with null bytes into a variable. Instead, it uses a variable to store the name of a file. The file, like any other file, may contain null bytes and can be used over and over. The file itself will most likely never be physically written to the disk.

Via a trap, bash deletes the file automatically, so you need not worry about removing it manually unless you are creating an a crazy array of garbage. Due to RAM buffering, this technique is decently fast.

Comment: There seems to be code missing. You also save the temporary file's pathname in `zHeader`, but then appear to remove `$zTemp` (but with literal quotes inserted around the name with `@Q`, for some unexplained reason). The answer is correct, but the code is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since a carriage return can be part of a file name, I like to use null terminated lists. But I cannot store the sting with null bytes because bash because Bash stores strings as simple C strings where the null byte is the string terminator and therefore cannot be part of the string itself.

To get around the problem, I create an array of strings where the null byte is assumed to exist after each element. The list itself obviously contains null bytes. I store the value containing null bytes in an array like this...

```bsh
    readarray -d $'\0' zArray < <(null_terminated_list_maker)
```

Then, I can reproduce the value with the null bytes like this...

```bsh
    [[ "${zArray[*]}" ]] && printf '%s\0' "${zArray[@]}"
```

In this manner, a bash array can be used to store any value containing null bytes.

The purpose of the `[[ "${zArray[*]}" ]]` test is to see if the array has any values at all (the null string is a value). The test solves the problem where if an empty array passed to printf like this, then printf will print one null byte, which is wrong. It should print nothing.

When representing completely arbitrary data, there is a problem: Did your input actually terminate with the null byte? This method needs expanded to handle data which may or may not end with the null byte.

Comment: Please note that the original problem arises from NULL bytes _inside_ a string variable, whereas your post concerns strings that are terminated by a NULL byte.

Comment: I read the first comment about data containing null bytes. Maybe my rewording of the first paragraph will help you understand. The problem with this solution is the terminating null byte.