# Send null byte in unix pipe

Tags: bash, io-redirection, null

I am trying to redirect python generated input to ELF 64-bit executable in bash 5.0.3. I am getting:

```
> ./bf <<< $(python2 -c "print('c'*6+b'\x00'+'c'*6)")
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
Enter password: Password didn't match
input: cccccccccccc
```

How can I allow a null byte in the input?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are able to pass null bytes across a pipe (like you say in the title), but the `bash` shell will not allow null bytes in expansions. It does not allow null bytes in expansions because the shell uses C strings to represent the results of expansions, and C strings are *terminated* by null bytes.

```
$ hexdump -C <<< $( python2 -c "print('c'*6+b'\x00'+'c'*6)" )
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
00000000  63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63  63 63 63 63 0a           |cccccccccccc.|
0000000d
```

Passing the data across a pipe is fine:

```
$ python2 -c "print('c'*6+b'\x00'+'c'*6)" | hexdump -C
00000000  63 63 63 63 63 63 00 63  63 63 63 63 63 0a        |cccccc.cccccc.|
0000000e
```

Redirecting a process substitution also works, as process substitutions don't expand to the data produced by the command but to the name of a file *containing* that data:

```
$ hexdump -C < <( python2 -c "print('c'*6+b'\x00'+'c'*6)" )
00000000  63 63 63 63 63 63 00 63  63 63 63 63 63 0a        |cccccc.cccccc.|
0000000e
```

So, the solution is to avoid having the shell store the data containing the null byte in a string, and instead pass the data over a pipe, without using a command substitution.  In your case

```
$ python2 -c "print('c'*6+b'\x00'+'c'*6)" | ./bf
```

Related:

- [How do I use null bytes in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174016/how-do-i-use-null-bytes-in-bash)
- [bash can't store hexvalue 0x00 in variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347390/bash-cant-store-hexvalue-0x00-in-variable)
- ... [and others](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+null+bytes+bash).

---

Or switch to `zsh` which *does* allow null bytes in strings:

```
$ hexdump -C <<< $( python2 -c "print('c'*6+b'\x00'+'c'*6)" )
00000000  63 63 63 63 63 63 00 63  63 63 63 63 63 0a        |cccccc.cccccc.|
0000000e
```

Comment: It also works with process substitution: `od -c < <(python2 -c "print('c'*6+b'\x00'+'c'*6)")`