# Bash - move/rename numeric sorted files from input number onwards

Tags: bash, files, for

I have a numbered list of files like this:

```
01_file_name.log
01_file_name.txt
02_file_name.log
02_file_name.txt
03_file_name.log
03_file_name.txt
04_file_name.log
04_file_name.txt
05_file_name.log
05_file_name.txt
```

I want to insert new files for all `03*` and `04*` files. So from number `03` on wards all files need to be moved/renamed with its leading number increased by 2, so the list would look like this:

```
01_file_name.log
01_file_name.txt
02_file_name.log
02_file_name.txt
05_file_name.log
05_file_name.txt
06_file_name.log
06_file_name.txt
07_file_name.log
07_file_name.txt
```

I'm thinking of something like:
`bash script.sh 03 02` while `03` on `$1` is the number of the file name to start with and `02` on `$2` the number to be added. I tried to achieve this with a nested `for-loop` but I had to give up on the combination of using a counter `((++))` to make the loop run only through the files from the given number on wards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want. One thing: It only works in BASH, I think.
`MAXDIGITS` is optional, I put it there in case you need to work with triple digits or more. If you don't use it, delete the corresponding lines.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    BOTTOM=$1
    SHIFT=$2
    MAXDIGITS=0$3
    for filename in $(ls -r *.{txt,log}); do
        PREFIX=${filename%%_*}
        NEWPREFIX=$(expr $PREFIX + $SHIFT)
        if [ $PREFIX -ge $BOTTOM ]; then
            NEWPREFIX=$(printf %${MAXDIGITS}d $NEWPREFIX)
            mv $filename ${NEWPREFIX}_${filename#*_}
        fi
    done
```

To use it:

```
    ./myscript <BOTTOM> <SHIFT> <MAXDIGITS>
    ### Example:
    ./miscript 03 02 2 #This means "Start at 03_filename.*, shift the prefixes by 2 and use 2 digits to construct the new prefixes".
```

If you have other files in the same directory that don't conform to the same syntax (prefix_filename.{txt,log}) you have to filter them.
Also, I used the "_" to separate prefix from filename, so if you change that you'll need to fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a `bash` one-liner that involves two *process substitutions* and a very simple `awk` procedure:

```
$ ls -r -1 *_file_name.{txt,log}    # list initial files in reverse order
05_file_name.log
05_file_name.txt
04_file_name.log
03_file_name.txt
03_file_name.log
03_file_name.txt
02_file_name.log
02_file_name.txt
01_file_name.log
01_file_name.txt

$ source <(awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"} $1>2 {prefix=$1+2; printf ("mv -f %s %0.2d_%s_%s\n",$0,prefix,$2,$3)}' <(ls -r -1 *_file_name.{log,txt}))

$ ls -1 *_file_name.{txt,log}     # list resulting files
01_file_name.log
01_file_name.txt
02_file_name.log
02_file_name.txt
05_file_name.log
05_file_name.txt
06_file_name.log
06_file_name.txt
07_file_name.log
07_file_name.txt
```

**Explanation:**

The one liner above is read, or at least "understood", from right to left.

- `ls -r -1 *_file_name.{log,txt}`  lists all files to be processed in reverse order, in one-column format.
  Note that if file prefixes (symbolized by `*`) include non-numeric characters, you might get unforeseen/unwanted results. To prevent that, filter files to be processed at this stage.
- `<(...)` process substitution. It allows the  previous result output to be referred to using a file descriptor, i.e. a special temporary file called a named pipe . For details issue `man bash` in terminal.
- `awk` script:

  - `BEGIN{FS="_"}`  before starting to process records, set the record's field separator to "_"  (awk's 1st block)
  - `awk`'s 2nd block's conditional, `$1>2`: only processes records whose filename's prefix is strictly greater than 2
  - `prefix=$1+2` defines awk's "prefix" internal variable. Make it numerically equal to prefix `$1` + 2
  - use `printf("my_format",var1,var2,...)` to print out formatted commands, separated by a new line. Note that formatting involves `%0.2d`, i.e. printing `awk`'s variable "prefix" as a two-digit number with 0 padding whenever necessary. Output is:
     
    `mv -f 05_file_name.log 07_file_name.log`
    `mv -f 05_file_name.txt 07_file_name.txt`
    `mv -f 04_file_name.log 06_file_name.log`
    `mv -f 04_file_name.txt 06_file_name.txt`
    `mv -f 03_file_name.log 05_file_name.log`
    `mv -f 03_file_name.txt 05_file_name.txt`
- treat that sorted output as yet another file (2nd process substitution) and source it to execute the `mv -f ...` commands.

If you wonder why repeatedly using *inbound or outbound process substitution* ( not a POSIX thing ! ) in `bash` is advantageous, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe) for instance.

**Final note:**

Including runtime parameters in the above one-liner and encapsulating it in an executable shell script is easy, starting with defining `VAR1` and `VAR2` by assignment to the `awk`'s procedure:

```
$ source <(awk -v VAR1=2 -v VAR2=2 'BEGIN{FS="_"} $1>VAR1 {prefix=$1+VAR2; printf ("mv -f %s %0.2d_%s_%s\n",$0,prefix,$2,$3)}' <(ls -r -1 *_file_name.{log,txt}))
```

And in an executable script, `script.sh`:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] ; then
    source  <(awk -v VAR1=$1 -v VAR2=$2 'BEGIN{FS="_"} $1>VAR1 {prefix=$1+VAR2; printf ("mv -f %s %0.2d_%s_%s\n",$0,prefix,$2,$3)}' 
              <(ls -r -1 *_file_name.{log,txt})
             )
    exit 0
else
    echo "   Usage: script.sh VAR1 VAR2.\n    Abort execution (exit code 1)."
    exit 1
fi
```

where `VAR1` and `VAR2` have the meaning defined in OP. If you need to use that script in production environment, I'd strongly recommend adding a number of checks and fail-safes to ensure that your input files and variables' values are the expected ones at all times.

The script by @MarceloCastro is fine, even though it's based on a `for` loop, which I tend to avoid whenever possible.  `for` loops tend to be slow, something you might notice if you process a *large* amount of files.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this script that would fit your goal.

```
for files in *.extensions
do
  num=$(echo "$files" | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c1-2)
  if [ $num -gt 2 ]; then
     AS=$((num+2))
     temp=$(echo "$files" | cut -c 3-)
     mv $files 0$AS"$temp"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload zmv
$ zmv -n -f '(<3->)(_*)(#qnOn)' '${(l:2::0:)$(($1+2))}$2'
mv -- 05_file_name.txt 07_file_name.txt
mv -- 05_file_name.log 07_file_name.log
mv -- 04_file_name.txt 06_file_name.txt
mv -- 04_file_name.log 06_file_name.log
mv -- 03_file_name.txt 05_file_name.txt
mv -- 03_file_name.log 05_file_name.log
```

Then remove `-n` (for dry-run) to actually do it.

- `zmv pattern replacement`: `zmv` is an autoloadable function that leverages the powerful zsh glob and expansion operators to do complex file renaming.
- `<x-y>` matches decimal number x to y.
- `(#q...)` glob qualifer
- `nOn`: `n`umerically `o`rder (reversed with capital O) by `n`ame. So `05...` will come before `04...` as needed here since we're incrementing the numbers.
- `${(l:n::padding:)expansion}`: `l`eft pad the expansion to length *n* using *padding*. So with `${(l:2::0:)}`, left pad to length 2 with 0s.
- `$(($1+2))`, the first captured group incremented by 2.
- `$2`: the second capture group: what's after the leading number.