# Executing a remote script from a code repository causes endless loop

Tags: bash, remote, source, control-flow, case

I often execute raw versions of remote Bash scripts in GitHub with this pattern:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<project>/<branch>/<path>/<file> | bash
```

Generally I can do it without problems but since I have added the following code to a certain script I get an endless loop of `echo` (it often occurs even if I just copy-paste it from GitHub to the terminal and execute directly):

```bsh
while true; do
    read -p "Example question: Do you wish to edit the PHP file now?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) nano PROJECT/PHP_FILE; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

I can at least partly solve the problem with something like:

```bsh
cd ACTION_DIRECTORY
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<project>/<branch>/<path>/<file> &&
source FILENAME &&
rm FILENAME
```

Which indicates that the `| bash` piping at least worsens the problem because the problem **always** happens with it.

Why would `echo "Please answer yes or no."` happen "endlessly"? (which I stop it with <kbd>CTRLC</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
Do you find any problem either in the single lined execution command and/or in the `while true; do case esac done`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would `echo …` happen "endlessly"?

With `wget … | bash` you pipe `wget` to `bash`. The stdin of `bash` comes from `wget`. `read` reads from the same stdin.

In general `read` reading from where the script comes from can consume parts of the script. In your case `bash` needs to read the whole `while … done` fragment (because e.g. it could be `while … done <whatever`). When `read` works, there is nothing more to read. Even the first `read` fails.

The script in question doesn't check if `read` fails.

Additionally `read -p` prints its prompt to stdin, so you never see the prompt.

If in the script there was `</dev/tty read …` or `while … done </dev/tty` then `read` would not read from the stdin of `bash`, it would read from the console. This would work but the method requires a change in the script itself. In general the change would break things if you run the script differently and need `read` to read from the stdin of the entire script that would happen to be different than `/dev/tty`.

But then `nano` (if you answered `y`) may complain about its stdin. If your fix was `</dev/tty read …` then `nano` would yield `Too many errors from stdin` because its stdin would be the (already broken) pipe from `wget`. If your fix was `while … done </dev/tty` then it would work.

With a bigger script there may be more places to "fix" this way. A proper general solution is not to hijack the stdin at all.

A general solution is to run one of these:

```
bash <(wget -O - …)
.    <(wget -O - …)
```

depending on if you want the script to run in a separate `bash` (like in your `wget … | bash …` try) or in the current shell (like in your `source FILENAME` solution).

Note you can now redirect the stdin independently, e.g.:

```
yes | bash <(wget -O - …)
```

The `<(some_command …)` syntax is called *process substitution*. It works [in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) and in few other shells but not in pure `sh` (see [bashisms](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)). Some interesting observations here: [*Process substitution and pipe*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17107/108618) (the "Preserving STDIN" section of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27346/108618) is exactly your question in a nutshell).

Comment: Thank you. I, as someone which is not a professional sysadmin and don't maintain servers daily, prefer not to go deep with the syntaxes that you have presented and stay with a more simple/traditional (non sugary-syntax) approach. Do you think that the alternative code I myself presented with `source` is good? Would you change anything there to make it more friendly with the loop and `case esac`? Thanks anyway,

Comment: I have posted a new question on the subject, you might want to check it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640206/understanding-the-process-substitution-concept

Comment: @variable_expander Your code with `source` realizes a good idea (download first, run later) with some potential flaws: (1) [unquoted `${HOME}`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618); (2) `&&` after `source …` makes `rm` depend on what the script does (this may or may not be what you want). // In general it's better to run a script (i.e. not to [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/108618)), unless you know you need to source. `bash FILENAME` runs it by a separate `bash`. `./FILENAME` runs it according to the shebang (if present), but `FILENAME` needs to be executable.