# Understanding the "process substitution" concept

Tags: bash, terminology

I seek a simple explanation about the term "process substitution" aimed for general audience / non professional sysadmins, which do server environment maintenance for personal projects once in a while and not daily for customers or companies, if its okay to ask for it here.

- What problem/s this concept was invented to solve
- What process is being substituted and with what (the name might mislead)?
- Is it also named "preserving stdin" and if so why? If the stdin device holds standard input which can be piped to another command, what is there to "preserve" further than that?

This might help me to understand the following command:

```
bash <(wget -O - URL)
```

<sub>**Note for newcomers:** `-O -` tells `wget` to write data to stdout;</sub>

Comment: see https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: @pLumo I understand that it is the piping of two or more commands (instead just one as in regular piping) to a command.

Comment: @ilkkachu these are the contexts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640180/executing-a-remote-script-from-a-code-repository-causes-endless-loop and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe/27346#27346

Comment: @ilkkachu I found the GNU explanation to be unclear/inaccessible for general public of users (as described in the question) ; the tag info doesn't mention why to do what it describes (`allows the input or output of a command to appear as a file` --- shouldn't this be done with variable substation and piping to a file?); I think I still miss what's "being substituted".

Comment: @ilkkachu I don't have such directories with files and I prefer not to create them (if there was a dummy content creator in that context I would do that); is there an even simpler explanation of this operation with files existing in generally any Linux system?

Comment: @variable_expander You have posted few questions and gained some reputation. [I encourage you to register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562/355310).

Comment: @ilkkachu what you wrote about me is wrong; I have made many software tests in my life, would probably do much more and often even enjoy making them, the test you have suggested is ambiguous: Two directories with how many files each by minimum? Special naming needed? Still, which "process" is being "substituted"? I just don't want to guess. I have even asked you about a test which doesn't include creating directories and files. I will gladly do testing if at least I know what approximately to expect. I want not to run commands when I don't have a minimal understanding of what to expect.

Comment: And BTW @ilkkachu I have done much more complicated software testing in my life then two `mkdir`s and about 2x2 `touch`es, in all humbleness.

Comment: @ilkkachu with all niceness and (vast) appreciation to you it didn't help me, or at least not a lot :) Anyway, the chapter `Important fact: there are two shells involved` in Kamil Maciorowski's answer basically explained the concept for me; perhaps only Brian Fox knows what was the original problem it was meant to solve originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Important fact: there are two shells involved

First note there are two shells involved. There is the outer Bash you work in, you invoke (type) `bash <(wget -O - URL)` in it. And there is the inner Bash that runs as a child process of the outer Bash when the command gets executed.

In other words the outer Bash accepts `bash <(wget -O - URL)` as a command and it spawns the inner Bash. I will distinguish the two where appropriate.

---

#### Important fact: there is more than one way to run code with Bash

There are few ways to make (an inner) Bash run some code:

1. `bash` can read code from its stdin:

   ```
   echo 'date; sleep 2; date' | bash
   ```

   The stdin can be the console. E.g. an interactive `bash` you normally work in reads from the console but it actually reads from its stdin because the console *is* its stdin.
2. `bash` can read code from a file:

   ```
   bash /path/to/some/file
   ```

   (The path may be relative.)
3. `bash` can read code from a command-line argument:

   ```
   bash -c 'date; sleep 2; date'
   ```

---

#### The context

In a comment you said the context is [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/640180/108618). My answer there advised to replace:

```
wget -O - URL | bash
```

with

```
bash <(wget -O - URL)
```

The first command makes the inner `bash` read from its stdin. What you seem not to have realized is that the second command makes the inner `bash` read from a file that is not its stdin.

---

#### What happens to `<(…)`

When you run `bash <(wget -O - URL)` in Bash, the outer Bash replaces `<(…)` with the path to some [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). After the replacement the actual command being run may be like:

```
bash /dev/fd/63
```

This spawns the inner Bash. It opens `/dev/fd/63` like it would open `/path/to/some/file`.

Thanks to the "magic" of process substitution `/dev/fd/63` is a pipe already connected to `wget -O - URL`.

<sup>Side note: on a system where `/dev/fd` is unavailable the outer Bash would use a truly named pipe (e.g. `/tmp/sh-np.pldKay`) to set this up.</sup>

---

#### The similarity

The connection from `wget` to (the inner) `bash` is similar in the two cases. When you run `wget -O - URL | bash`, `bash` reads code from its stdin which is a pipe `wget` writes to. When you run `bash <(wget -O - URL)`, `bash` reads code from another file (i.e. not from its stdin) which is a pipe `wget` writes to. In both cases the outer Bash sets the pipe up.

---

#### The difference

The difference is with process substitution the stdin of the inner Bash is not used to pass code to it. The stdin can be used for another purpose. E.g. the stdin can be the console and `read` in the code can read from it.

---

#### Answers to your explicit questions

- > What problem/s this concept was invented to solve

  When a command expects a pathname (path to a file) and you want to pipe something in instead of providing a regular file, you can create a named pipe and achieve the goal. This requires actually creating a pipe (`mkfifo`), piping something to it (in the background or in another console), running the command and finally removing the named pipe (`rm`).

  With process substitution Bash handles the piping. It's convenient.
- > What process is being substituted and with what?

  In `bash <(wget -O - URL)` the `<(wget -O - URL)` syntax is substituted with a path to some file, only then the command is executed (and it's `bash /dev/fd/63` or similar). The outer Bash prepares the file, so reading from it means reading what `wget -O - URL` (the process) writes. The file is actually a pipe, not a regular file.
- > Is it also named "preserving stdin" and if so why?

  "Preserving stdin" happens, but it's not an alternative name for process substitution. It's not a *formal* name for what happens either.

  When you run (inner) `bash …` in (outer) Bash, the inner Bash gets its stdin inherited from the outer Bash (i.e. it's the same file). The stdin may be the console.

  But if you run `wget … | bash …` instead, the inner Bash will see data from `wget` on its own stdin. Now some part of the inner Bash (e.g. the `read` *builtin*) or some child of the inner Bash may want to read something from stdin. They expect input from a console or whatever, but *not* the code the inner Bash should execute. But because the stdin of the inner Bash is a pipe from `wget`, builtins will use it and child processes will inherit it as *their* stdins. They won't inherit the stdin of the outer Bash.

  By using process substitution instead of piping code via the stdin of (the inner) `bash`, you make the stdin of the outer Bash available for builtins and children of the inner Bash. You *preserve* the stdin of the outer Bash for builtins and children of the inner Bash. At the same time you protect the stream of code the inner Bash reads and executes from being read by its builtins or children.

  This works only because `bash` allows you to provide code in a file specified as a command line argument. If (the inner) Bash supported reading code from stdin only, then you would have to provide code via its stdin. In such case process substitution could not solve [the issue you had](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/640180/108618).

Comment: [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/355310).

Comment: If I'd known you were writing an answer, I wouldn't have closed it. Sorry.

Comment: @ilkkachu No harm done. If I knew valuable posts on U&L better, I may have found a duplicate by myself and voted to close. I actually noticed the closure but tried my luck anyway. :) I did this because I think the information about how Bash can read code plus the distinction between the outer Bash and the inner Bash may help the OP better than examples where Bash runs some other commands.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski please consider to shorten the answer a bit; I think I don't have the mental ability to handle such a long text in English (not my native language) about advanced subjects in *nix (at least for me), especially when it's not splitted to chapters. I tried to edit to add a chapter and a "stop, wait and think about it" `that said;` divider but I am still having hard time understanding what's going on, especially in the last three passages where I felt mentally exhausted. Of course, the problem here is from my side, not of yours; your try to help me is venerated.

Comment: Link to suggested edit in case community members reject it from whatever reason: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/371386