# Pipe output of two commands into another script as arguments

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, io, stdout, stdin

ntopng can handle multiple network interfaces and I've a script that takes the name of the interface and outputs it in to stdout. I can pipe this output into ntopng

```
my_packet_tracer.sh | ntopng -i -
```

And I see the Interface in ntopng admin panel as `stdin`

[image]

I would like to run my script for the second network interface and also pipe the output in to ntopng, but since it is already running I can not start second process.

How could I pipe the output of two scripts as arguments of ntopng in following way?:

```
my_pkg_trace.sh eth0 >--,
                        |-- ntopng -i output1 -i output2
my_pkg_trace.sh wan  >--'
```

Comment: Does this work: `ntopng -i <(my_pkg_trace.sh eth0) -i <(my_pkg_trace.sh wan)`? If it does, we can probably close as a duplicate of [Process substitution and pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17107).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ntopng -i <(my_pkg_trace.sh eth0) -i <(my_pkg_trace.sh wan)
```

Comment: can I put it into shellscript?